# Ignore devdependencies in Vue production build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I'm using Vue with the latest CLI. When developing locally, I use the `faker` npm package with a fakeserver, e.g:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "faker": "^4.1.0"
    "json-server": "^0.14.2"
}
```

None of these packages are included in my main.js or any script files or components used in production. However, they are still bundled in chunk-vendor.js when i run `npm run build`. Why is that? Isn't webpack's tree-shaking supposed to remove non used packages?

Comment: are any of your dependencies using faker in their dependencies? because devDependencies are usually not bundled

Comment: @DhananjaiPai Good question, is there an easy way to check? Rather than checking each package.json

Comment: @Johan You could simply search for a file (.json) in the editor itself having `faker` or `json-server` right. If found at `package.json` `dependencies` of any of `node_modules` packages other than this.

Comment: devDependicies are not bundeled on production, by default

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you have inadvertently included `faker` somewhere in your project. E.g. you included a component, which includes a library, which includes `faker`. In reference to an earlier comment, you can run `npm ls` to see if it appears more than once in your dependency tree, and if so which packages are including it.